# Linux prompt missing brackets

Tags: bash, root, prompt, chroot

I'm using centos in my VPS server and guest system. There're two logins for a guest system. One is root and one is regular. After I mounted the guest system and chroot to the mounting directory, I switched to the regular account in the mounted guest system. Then the brackets missed as shown below:

```
[root@server image]# chroot /mnt/guest34
[root@server /]# su - regular
-bash-4.1$ sd
-bash: sd: command not found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should read about `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`. The bracketed information is just a preference in those files which typically live in your home directory and/or `/etc/profile` (look for the line that starts `PS1=`). I'm assuming that when you're chrooted, that user does not have access to its home folder to load these files, so your prompt is, essentially, un-customized.

Most modern distros will display something like `[user@server directory]#` but this behavior is controlled by these two files. What you're seeing is bash with no customizations, since they cannot be loaded from the user's home.

Answer (score 2):

What's your question?

The appearance of the prompt is defined by the `$PS1` variable. Your `regular` account just doesn't have the brackets in the variable's value.

If you want your `regular` prompt to look like your `root` prompt, first log in as `root` and `echo $PS1` and copy or write down the value.  Then switch to `regular` and set that as the value of `$PS1`.  Save it in `~/.bashrc` if you want it to stick.

All of this is explained in greater detail in `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

or, you could just clone this:

```
git clone git://github.com/christopher-barry/bash-color-tools.git
```

run ./install from the root of the tree, and have custom theme-able color prompts :)